# Mobile: Javascript doesnt work after redirecting

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile, redirect

I have a Javascript on my resume page that triggers by the onLoad function when someone enters my site, after I setup a redirect to a different page (different language version with the same javascript), the script doesn't trigger onLoad after being redirected, I had to manually reload the page to run the script. I checked the internet for suggestions, tried jQuery suggestions regarding refresh the site upon loading on StackOverflow and didn't work at all and the window.document.redirect() Javascript code all it does is refreshing my page constantly. I tried writing the scripts both on my main page and external script sheet, but no avail. I saw also suggestions about refreshing the page in intervals, but I don't want such a thing nor reloading after some time.

Instead of posting the codes, I put links to two modified pages to demonstrate my problem.

http://lucianzafari.coffeecup.com/test1.html

So my question is: how to make a mobile page to run the scripts on the redirected page? (post-redirect scripting) (the desktop version works perfectly)

Comment: How is the redirect done?  Is it in script, or from a button or link click?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**maybe not the answer**

Fix this first **script between head and body** by mooving it in either HEAD or BODY tag :

```
</head>
<script src="stylesheets/MobileScript.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'> 
function timerS()
{
var y = new Date();
var timeH = y.getHours();
var timeM = y.getMinutes();

var d =  document.body.id

    if ( (timeH >= "4" && timeH <="11") && timeM <="59")
        {
            document.getElementById("headsup").src="images/morning.jpg";
            document.getElementById("welcome").innerHTML = "Dobré Ráno";
        }
    else if ( (timeH >= "12" && timeH <="16") && timeM <="59") 
        {
            document.getElementById("headsup").src="images/afternoon.jpg";
            document.getElementById("welcome").innerHTML = "Dobrý Deň";
        }
    else if ( (timeH >= "17" && timeH <="19") && timeM <="59") 
        {
            document.getElementById("headsup").src="images/sunset.jpg";
            document.getElementById("welcome").innerHTML = "Dobrý Večer";
        }
    else if ( (timeH >= "20" && timeH <="23") && timeM <="59") 
        {
            document.getElementById("headsup").src="images/moon.jpg";
        }
    else if ( (timeH >= "0" && timeH <="3") && timeM <="59") 
        {
            document.getElementById("headsup").src="images/moon.jpg";
        }

};
</script>
<body id="slovak" onload="timerS()">
```